# How to display custom error message for optional and conditional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I’m trying to implement a command line argument in a Python script that is both conditional and optional. So the valid usage would be something like that shown below, which says “-a” is optional, and “-b” is optional but only valid if “-a” is specified.

```
[-a argumentA [-b argumentB]]
```

I have a solution for doing this using argparse, but I am not able to get the help and error text to do what I want. This is the solution I have:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-a", "--AAA", dest="aaa_arg", help="this is the 'a' argument")

namespace, extra = parser.parse_known_args()
if namespace.aaa_arg != None:
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--BBB", dest="bbb_arg", help="only use 'b' when 'a' is used")

myArgs = parser.parse_args()

if myArgs.aaa_arg != None:
    print("AAA: " + myArgs.aaa_arg)
    if myArgs.bbb_arg != None:
        print("BBB: " + myArgs.bbb_arg)
```

The output for various parameters on the command line is:

```
>py test.py

>py test.py -a something
AAA: something

>py test.py -a something -b somethingElse
AAA: something
BBB: somethingElse

>py test.py -b somethingElse
usage: test.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -b somethingElse

>py test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                   show this help message and exit
  -a AAA_ARG, --AAA AAA_ARG    this is the 'a' argument

>
```

The issue is that a user who has been told that “-b” is a valid argument will be confused by the error message that says “-b somethingElse” is unrecognized. If that user then displays the help, they will not see “-b” listed.

Fixing the help is fairly simple. The second version below uses conflict_handler in the ArgumentParser to allow a custom help message.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(conflict_handler="resolve")
parser.add_argument("-h", "--help", action="store_true", dest="display_help")

parser.add_argument("-a", "--AAA", dest="aaa_arg", help="this is the 'a' argument")

namespace, extra = parser.parse_known_args()
if namespace.aaa_arg != None:
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--BBB", dest="bbb_arg", help="only use 'b' when 'a' is used")

myArgs = parser.parse_args()

if myArgs.display_help:
    print('''usage: test2.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG [-b BBB_ARG]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                   show this help message and exit
  -a AAA_ARG, --AAA AAA_ARG    this is the 'a' argument
  -b BBB_ARG, --BBB BBB_ARG    only use 'b' when 'a' is used''')
else:    
    if myArgs.aaa_arg != None:
        print("AAA: " + myArgs.aaa_arg)
        if myArgs.bbb_arg != None:
            print("BBB: " + myArgs.bbb_arg)
```

As you can see in the output below, the help message lists “-b” as a valid argument; however, the error message still states that “-b somethingElse” is unrecognized.

```
>py test2.py

>py test2.py -a something
AAA: something

>py test2.py -a something -b somethingElse
AAA: something
BBB: somethingElse

>py test2.py -b somethingElse
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG]
test2.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -b somethingElse

>py test2.py -h
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG [-b BBB_ARG]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                   show this help message and exit
  -a AAA_ARG, --AAA AAA_ARG    this is the 'a' argument
  -b BBB_ARG, --BBB BBB_ARG    only use 'b' when 'a' is used

>
```

What I would really like to have is something like the output shown below (this output was created manually as an example, not by Python):

```
>py test3.py

>py test3.py -a something
AAA: something

>py test3.py -a something -b somethingElse
AAA: something
BBB: somethingElse

>py test3.py -b somethingElse
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG [-b BBB_ARG]]
test2.py: only use 'b' when 'a' is used

>py test3.py -h
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a AAA_ARG [-b BBB_ARG]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                   show this help message and exit
  -a AAA_ARG, --AAA AAA_ARG    this is the 'a' argument
  -b BBB_ARG, --BBB BBB_ARG    only use 'b' when 'a' is used

>
```

Is there a way to customize the error message for the "-b" option?

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestions from @hpaulj, I separated the parsing and the conditional checking. The solution adds both the “-a” and “-b” arguments to the parser, then checks the conditional and sets an error with a cutom message.

Adding a custom usage message to the ArgumentParser and tweaking the argument names displayed by help via the metavar attibute on the arguments matches up the uasge statement and the argument descriptions in the help message.
The end result is simpler than what I started out with: no need to parse twice, and no need for a custom help message.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="%(prog)s [-h] [-a argA [-b argB]]")

parser.add_argument("-a", "--AAA", metavar="argA", dest="aaa_arg", help="this is the 'a' argument")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--BBB", metavar="argB", dest="bbb_arg", help="only use 'b' when 'a' is used")

myArgs = parser.parse_args()

if myArgs.aaa_arg == None and myArgs.bbb_arg != None:
    parser.error("only use 'b' when 'a' is used")

if myArgs.aaa_arg != None:
    print("AAA: " + myArgs.aaa_arg)
    if myArgs.bbb_arg != None:
        print("BBB: " + myArgs.bbb_arg)




>py test2.py

>py test2.py -a something
AAA: something

>py test2.py -a something -b somethingElse
AAA: something
BBB: somethingElse

>py test2.py -b somethingElse
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a argA [-b argB]]
test2.py: error: only use 'b' when 'a' is used

>py test2.py -h
usage: test2.py [-h] [-a argA [-b argB]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -a argA, --AAA argA  this is the 'a' argument
  -b argB, --BBB argB  only use 'b' when 'a' is used

>
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, your suggestions got me moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first try

> The issue is that a user who has been told that “-b” is a valid argument will be confused by the error message that says “-b somethingElse” is unrecognized. If that user then displays the help, they will not see “-b” listed.

The first `parse_known_args()` handles, or rather ignores, the `-b`.  But it acts on the `-h`.  The second `parse_args()` is the one that's complaining about the unrecognized `-b`.

`ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` creates a parser without the automatic help; that's an alternative to your `resolve`.  You could add the custom or standard help after first `parse_know_args`.

Another thing to consider is a custom `usage` string.

If you don't want it to complain about `-b`, skip the `parse_args` or use `parse_known_args` again.

`parser.error('custom message')` can be used to display a custom error with usage.

`argparse` does not provide a convenient way making one argument conditional on another.  Often we recommend doing that kind of testing after parsing, rather than trying to do it all while parsing (or with 2 parsing calls).  Keep in mind that `argparse` tries to handle `optionals` in any order: `-a foo -b bar` the same as `-b bar -a foo`.